# JS puppeteer using for loop to iterate over links

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to iterate over unique youtube video links to get screenshot.

After debugging, I noticed for the  forloop below, JS spawn 2 process threads, 1 for each index i . The processALink() function in the second thread seems to start before the processALink() in the first thread has ended fully.

Why is this happening? I thought using async/wait  stops this from happening.

The forloop is inside a async function. The code below is just a snippet from the oringinal source code.

```
 for(let i = 0; i<2; i++){
    var link = linksArr[i];
    var label = labelsArr[i];
    await proccessALink(link, label)
  }
```

Function def for processALink()

```
var proccessALink = async (link,label)=>{
    //set download path 
    var downloadPath  = 'data/train/'+label;
    //parse the url
    var urlToScreenshot = parseUrl(link)
    //Give a URL it will take a screen shot 
    if (validUrl.isWebUri(urlToScreenshot)) {
      // console.log('Screenshotting: ' + urlToScreenshot + '&t=' + req.query.t)
      console.log('Screenshotting: ' + link)
      ;(async () => {

        //Logic to login to youtube below
        //await login();
        //go to the url and wait till all the content is loaded.
        await page.goto(link, {
          waitUntil: 'networkidle'
          //waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'
        })
        //await page.waitForNavigation();

        //Find the video player in the page 
        const video = await page.$('.html5-video-player')
        await page.content();

        //Run some command on consoleDev 
        await page.evaluate(() => {
          // Hide youtube player controls.
          let dom = document.querySelector('.ytp-chrome-bottom')
          if(dom != null){
            dom.style.display = 'none'
          }
        })

        await video.screenshot({path: downloadPath});

      })()
    } else {
      res.send('Invalid url: ' + urlToScreenshot)
    }

  }
```

Comment: Kindly add the function definition for `processALink()`.

Comment: @ryeballar, I have added the function def as asked. I also noticed the 'page' variable is shared by the second thread. The second thread update the page variable before the frist thread is over.

Comment: This is because you're defining an IIFE function inside `processALink()` without `await`. Additionally I don't think you need to define it as such..

Comment: Lastly, if you're already using `const` and `let`, then you don't need to use `var` as it doesn't respect block scope.

Comment: @ryeballar, oh snap, Yeah that true! Thanks alot.

Comment: If this has resolved your problem, kindly accept the answer I provided below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) inside `processALink()` and it should resolve the issue of running multiple screenshots at the same time.

```
const proccessALink = async(link, label) => {
  //set download path 
  const downloadPath = 'data/train/' + label;
  //parse the url
  const urlToScreenshot = parseUrl(link)
  //Give a URL it will take a screen shot 
  if (validUrl.isWebUri(urlToScreenshot)) {
    // console.log('Screenshotting: ' + urlToScreenshot + '&t=' + req.query.t)
    console.log('Screenshotting: ' + link);
    //Logic to login to youtube below
    //await login();
    //go to the url and wait till all the content is loaded.
    await page.goto(link, {
      waitUntil: 'networkidle'
      //waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'
    })
    //await page.waitForNavigation();

    //Find the video player in the page 
    const video = await page.$('.html5-video-player')
    await page.content();

    //Run some command on consoleDev 
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      // Hide youtube player controls.
      let dom = document.querySelector('.ytp-chrome-bottom')
      if (dom != null) {
        dom.style.display = 'none'
      }
    })

    await video.screenshot({
      path: downloadPath
    });
  } else {
    res.send('Invalid url: ' + urlToScreenshot)
  }

}
```